# Very slow loading upon locale change

Tags: magento-2.1, locale, apache2

I changed my Magento 2 store locale to Russian using the etws/magento-language-ru_ru plugin and the site loading speed significantly increased. Chrome shows that the waiting time (TTFB) is 12-15 seconds at least.

I'm using Apache 2. It server other files in a timely manner. When I use English as the store locale it takes a few seconds to load the page.

How do I fix the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: you can try: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-performance-optimization/

Comment: @nikunj see my below answer for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need deploy your language to run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ru_RU en_US
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Let me know if you have any issue.